# Getting an error message trying to install python3.11 into my newly created virtual environment venv

Tags: python, pip

```
(venv) (base) -Mac-Pro financial_tool_kit % python --version

Python 3.9.7

(venv) (base) -Mac-Pro financial_tool_kit % pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (23.1.2)
(venv) (base) -Mac-Pro financial_tool_kit % python -m pip install python==3.11

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.11 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.11
```

Comment: On my system python3.11 is installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

Comment: see `python3 --version` is it 3.11, also is this anaconda you have installed ?

Comment: No, my python3 --version is 3.9.7.  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current is set to 3.11.  if that helps

Comment: virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3.11 venv seemed to work

Comment: don't know how it is configured this way. but you can use `pyenv` for better use, where with pyenv you can download multiple Python versions, set whichever version you want to work with and create virtual env of those versions for your project